# dompdf render doesn't look like html

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, dompdf

i use dompdf with codeigniter to convert my php (html) file into pdf.

My problem is the dompdf render doesn't appear like my php page :

Style for php file :

```
body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
color:#000;}
.xls {
border-top:1px solid #868686; }
.xls tr > td {
border-right:1px solid #868686;  padding: 2px 3px 2px 5px;}
.t-pad tr > td {
border-right:1px solid #868686;  padding: 2px 3px 2px 5px;}
.xls tr:first-child >td {
border-top:1px solid #868686;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
.xls tr:last-child >td {
border-bottom:1px solid #868686;
text-align: center;
}
.xls {
border-right:1px solid #868686;
border-left:1px solid #868686;
}
.xls .m-td{
border-bottom: 0 none !important;
border-left: 1px solid #868686;
border-right: 1px solid #868686;
border-top: 0 none !important;}
.last-col{border-right:0 !important;
border-top: 0 none !important; }
.td-tab{ padding:10px 10px 10px 20px !important;}
.tab-center{ border-left: 1px solid #868686; }
.tab-center td{ padding: 0 0 0 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #868686; }

.first-td  {
border-top: 1px solid #868686 !important;
}
.border-r{border-right: 1px solid #868686 !important;}
.tab-cc{
 border: 1px solid #868686;

 }
 .border-bt{border-bottom: 1px solid #868686 !important;}
 .titre-tab {
   background:#b2b1b1;

 }
```

and it appear like :

http://info-du-jour.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/php.png

fil in controller to convert into pdf :

```
  $data = $this->data_paie($ids);

            $this->load->view('paie/fdp_etat', $data);
    // Get output html
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    // Load library
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

    // Convert to PDF
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
            $this->dompdf->stream("fiche_de_paie.pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));
```

and it look like

http://info-du-jour.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/dompdf.png

html rendering code :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="50" valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;">BULLETIN DE PAIE</td>
                    <td align="right">
                                                                            <img src="/logo/logo_simple1.jpg" 
                                         width="136" height="31" />
                                                                        </td>
                  </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" width="101"><strong>Période :</strong></td>
        <td width="197" colspan="3" align="center">
            <div style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">
                01-06-2014 au 30-06-2014                </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="48%" valign="top">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="tab-cc t-pad" width="100%" style="height:150px;">
      <tr>

        <td width="137"><strong>Matricule</strong></td>
        <td width="217">SAL003</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td><b>Nom et Prénom</b></td>
        <td>AYARI Marwa</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td><strong>Fonction</strong></td>
        <td>Développeur</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td><strong>Sit. familiale</strong></td>
        <td>Marié </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td><strong>Nbre d'enfants</strong></td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="48%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="tab-cc" style="height:150px;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><b>EMPLOYEUR</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>TOPO+</strong><br />
          6 Rue des Cyclamens<br />
           1004 EL MENZAH 5, ARIANA.<br />
          CNSS Employeur :  45454 </td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0"  class="tab-cc xls" width="48%" >
<tr>
<td rowspan="2"><b>Droit congés payés</b></td>
<td align="center">Ancien solde</td>
<td align="center">(+) Droits</td>
<td align="center">(-) Pris</td>
<td align="center">Nouv. solde</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">12</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td align="center">5</td>
<td align="center">2</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="xls">
<tr class="titre-tab">
<td height="40"><strong>Désignation</strong></td>
<td><strong>Nombre</strong></td>
<td><strong>Base</strong></td>
<td><strong>Gains</strong></td>
<td><strong>Retenues</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre de jours de présence</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">26</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Salaire de base</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">1258,799</td>
<td align="right">1258,799</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<!-- autant de lignes que de primes dans la conv collective -->
            <tr>
            <td>Indemnité de transport</td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp; </td>
            <td align="right">40,000</td>
            <td align="right">40,000</td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Prime de présence</td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp; </td>
            <td align="right">2,080</td>
            <td align="right">2,080</td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Indemnité de déplacement</td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp; </td>
            <td align="right">0,000</td>
            <td align="right">0,000</td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

 <tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Total Brut</b></td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">1300,879</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Retenu C.N.S.S</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">1300,879</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">119,421</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>SALAIRE IMPOSABLE</b></td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">1181,458</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>IRPP</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">173,646</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Total Cotisations</b></td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">293,067</td>
</tr>
<tr height="35">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right">&nbsp; </td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr height="21">
  <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>      
 </tr>
 <tr height="21">
  <td width="66%" align="right"><strong>Net à Payer</strong></td>
  <td width="3%"></td>
  <td width="2%"></td>
  <td width="29%" colspan="2" align="right" class="tab-cc"><span style="font-weight:bold;padding-right: 4px;">1007,812</span> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="21">
  <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be easier to determine the issue to see the full HTML+CSS. You can get the HTML that dompdf is parsing by using `$dompdf->output_html()` (v0.6.0). Also, which version of dompdf are you using?

Comment: @version 0.5.1.htischer.20090507

Comment: If you can I recommend you update to the latest version. Many improvements have been made.

Comment: Houston, i v problem with migration :(
when i replace old folders with news of the lateste version dowloaded from Github, i ve this message when tryong to use dompdf :

`php-font-lib/classes/Font.php: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

so i download fil php-font-lib-master and put folders into mine but ther's no folder classes so always the same problems !!

som forum suggest to me to put `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD", false);`

but with this another problem :
`Class 'DOMPDF' not found in dev\application\libraries\dompdf_gen.php on line 27`

:(

Comment: i'm sorry for the english, i'm frensh speaker :(

Comment: The source download from github only includes the dompdf files. Downloading the latest php-font-lib was the correct choice, but the code layout has changed significantly since we released 0.6.0. Try the official release download (the green button) on the [dompdf 0.6.0 release page](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.1), which includes a copy of php-font-lib.

Comment: (BTW, wo need to apologize for your English, it's quite good.)

Comment: Migration ok !! it's working !!
and rendering is better but still not exactly the same of html version but i think that can satisfy me !!

thank you very much Brian for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$html = $this->output->get_output();` you can get the same HTML as it is rendering on browser . for that you need to make changes in script like :

```
$html = $this->load->view('paie/fdp_etat', $data , true); // so now your `$html` will be string which will return string from your view and both will be same.
```

For reference [SEE HERE](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)